# Netbeans 7.0.1 unable to commit deleted files

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans7.0

Since my update to Netbeans 7.0.1 I am unable to commit locally deleted files through subversion. They come up in the commit view every time and there is no error message when I commit, they just arent removed from the repository and thus comes up for every commit I do.

Has anyone else experienced this? It was working great in 6.9.1 and I'm thinking of downgrading...

Comment: I was just told about this problem by a coworker a few hours ago. She solved it using TortoiseSVN and I'm using git so I can't offer a solution.
When I have problems with Netbeans and SVN (rare ocurrence) I delete the .netbeans/xx/var/cache/svn directory. (xx being the version number)

Comment: Netbeans has problems synchronizing with subversion in some instances. Most of the time this happens when you have deleted, restored, and deleted again files, with out committing. Just get RapidSVN, access the repository, fix the directories and do an update.

Comment: Fortunately we have moved on to git so I am not having this issue any more..

Comment: Might want to close the question then.